# Why don't we have to use polynomial long division on quadratic irreducible partial fractions in this case?

Tags: calculus

For $(x^2+3x+1)
/(x^2+1)^2 $

Why don't we have to use polynomial long division in this case since the degree of the denominator has the same magnitude of degree as the numerator before doing partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: We don't have to, we can go backwards, make ansatz, multiply by least common multiple for denominator and solve linear equation system that arises.

Comment: If you need to integrate, $$\dfrac{x^2+3x+1}{(x^2+1)^2}=\dfrac1{x^2+1}+\dfrac{3x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Comment: The numerator has degree 2 and the denominator degree 4.

Answer (score 2):

You can use long division in this particular case, where the denominator is the power of a quadratic. But it is not much help in other cases.

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{x^2+3x+1}{(x^2+1)^2}&=&\frac{x^2+3x+1}{x^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+1}\\
&=&\left(1+\frac{3x}{x^2+1}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+1}\\
&=&\frac{1}{x^2+1}+\frac{3x}{(x^2+1)^2}
\end{eqnarray}

**ADDENDUM:** Here is another demonstration of the technique:

Decompose $\dfrac{x^4+1}{(x^2+x+1)^3}$

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{x^4+1}{(x^2+x+1)^3}&=&\left(\frac{x^4+1}{x^2+x+1}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}\\
&=&\left(x^2-x+\frac{x+1}{x+x+1}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}\\
&=&\left(\frac{x^2-x}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{x+1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\\
&=&\left(1-\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{x+1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}\\
&=&\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}-\frac{2x+1}{(x^2+x+1)^2}+\frac{x+1}{(x^2+x+1)^3}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

We don't have to, we can go backwards, make ansatz, multiply by least common multiple for denominator and solve linear equation system that arises.

$$\frac{a}{x^2+1} + \frac{bx+c}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Now multiply both numerator and denominator of first term by $x^2+1$

$$\frac{a(x^2+1) + bx+c}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

Now set up equations for what $a$, $b$ and $c$ are. Can you finish from here?

Comment: @happysaint it is for the reason John writes in comment. The degrees of polynomials. If the one on top is greater than the one on bottom we have to use it, if it is equal or smaller, we can use this method I show instead if we want to.

Comment: Ok, so is it because x^2+3x+1 can be simplified to x(x+3)+1 and the numerator factor is then less than denominator factor? I get the rest of the process it's just the degree throwing me off.

Comment: The degree of top is 2 because largest exponent is 2. The degree of bottom polynomial is 4 because largest exponent is 4. You will see if you calculate $(x^2+1)^2 = (x^2+1)(x^2+1) = x^4+2x^2+1$ you have one term with $x^4$ there so order for that one is 4.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks that's exactly what I needed to see, I had a brain fart and was making (x^2+1)^2 into something different